# finding the Lebesgue measure of the set $A = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 | y^2 + z^2 \le 4, 0 \le x \le 4, x \le 6-y-z \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

I want to find the Lebesgue measure, denoted $u$, of this (closed and thus measurable) set.
$$A = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 | y^2 + z^2 \le 4, 0 \le x \le 4, x \le 6-y-z \}$$

This is a cylinder cut by a plane.

When $x = 4, z = 2$ the plane cuts the $y$ axis in zero, so, if I look at where x changes, this divides the projection on the $x = 0$ plane in two semicircles of radius $2$ (correct?) that I call $B$ and $C$.

I decide to start integrating the $x$ variable first

$$u(A) = \int_B \int_0^{6-y-z}dx \ d(y,z) + \int_C \int_0^4 dx \ d(y,z) = $$

$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^2 6p -p^2cos\theta - p^2sin\theta \ dp \ d\theta + \int_0^\pi \int_0^2 4p \ d p \ d\theta = 20 \pi$$

But this is impossible because it's more than the volume of the complete cylinder that is $16 \pi$.

Corrections of my error and different approaches are welcome.